# React login authentication in child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a App component where user login into the application and the remaining components must verify auth guard before rendering, otherwise redirect to login page i.e. App component.

I am trying to pass the state variable from App component to the child components via a PrivateRouter as my auth guard. But its not working. Before this i have tried also using `react-router v4` to use render inside the route.

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import history from './History';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      authenticated: false
    };

  this.handleUserChange = this.handleUserChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}


handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post('https://api.github.com/user',{}, {
      auth: {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({
        authenticated : true,
      });
      history.push({pathname: '/home', state: { detail: response.data }});
      history.go('/home');
    }).catch(function(error) {
      this.setState({
        authenticated : false,
      });
      console.log('Error on Authentication' + error);
  });
}

handleUserChange(event){
    this.setState({
      username : event.target.value,
    });
}

handlePasswordChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    password: event.target.value
  });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div className='loginForm'>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            username :
            <input type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUserChange} required/>
          </label>
          <label>
            password :
            <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} required/>
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="LogIn" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

import {
  Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';
import User from './User';
import history from './History';

ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/user" component={User} />
 </Switch>
</Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

## Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import './Home.css';
import history from './History';


// When suggestion is clicked, Autosuggest needs to populate the input
// based on the clicked suggestion. Teach Autosuggest how to calculate the
// input value for every given suggestion.
const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion;

// Use your imagination to render suggestions.
const renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
  <div>
    {suggestion}
  </div>
);

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Autosuggest is a controlled component.
    // This means that you need to provide an input value
    // and an onChange handler that updates this value (see below).
    // Suggestions also need to be provided to the Autosuggest,
    // and they are initially empty because the Autosuggest is closed.
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: [],
      timeout: 0
    };
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
   console.log('=====++++ ' + newValue);
  };

  onSuggestionSelected = (event, { suggestion, suggestionValue, suggestionIndex, sectionIndex, method }) => {
    console.log("Get the user +++++++++ " + suggestionValue);
   if(suggestionValue && suggestionValue.length >= 1){
       axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/'+ suggestionValue)
       .then((response) => {
          console.log("user selected : "+ response.data.avatar_url);
          history.push({pathname: '/user', state: { detail: response.data }});
          history.go('/user');
       }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Error on Authentication' + error);
        });
     }
  };

  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to update suggestions.
  // You already implemented this logic above, so just use it.
  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    if(this.timeout) clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.getSuggestions();
      }, 500);
  };

getSuggestions = () =>{
  if(this.state.value && this.state.value.length >= 1){
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/search/users',{
    params: {
      q: this.state.value,
      in:'login',
      type:'Users'
    }
  }).then((response) => {
      console.log("users login : "+ response.data.items);
      const userNames = response.data.items.map(item => item.login);
      console.log("===== " + userNames);
        this.setState({
          suggestions: userNames
        })
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error on Authentication' + error);
   });
 }
};

  // Autosuggest will call this function every time you need to clear suggestions.
  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: []
    });
  };


  render(){

    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;

    // Autosuggest will pass through all these props to the input.
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: 'Type a userName',
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    return (
      <div>
      <div>
        Home page {this.props.location.state.detail.login}
      </div>
      <div>
          <Autosuggest
            suggestions={suggestions}
            onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
            onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
            getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
            renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
            inputProps={inputProps}
            onSuggestionSelected={this.onSuggestionSelected}
          />
      </div>
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default Home;
```

## PrivateRouter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Redirect,
  Route,
  } from "react-router-dom";



const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      props.authenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

How can pass state variable `authenticated` to `PrivateRouter` or is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Use redux for that. Passing authenticated from parent to all childs is expensive. Set authenticated in redux store from parent component and get authentication from redux store and validate in any of the child components or use onEnter prop on routes which will take a function and that function get the state from redux and redirects if user is authenticated. Second option will be global

Comment: I don't want to do it with redux as i am fairly new to react learning.